# Rails - how can I have a Class level method in an active record model that sorts by lower case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, sorting, model

In ruby I can do `my_ar_collection.sort_by{ |element| element.name.downcase}` in my controller.

I want to have an ActiveRecord class method that does that.

Right now I have:

```
def self.ordered
  order(:name)
end
```

But I want to add `.downcase` to it.  I've tried a number of ways, such as using `sort_by` and using `order :field.downcase` but with no luck

Comment: Did you try `order(lower(name))` um... I can't recall the syntax now; that might only work for a default_order. You could do it as a `where`, certainly. Oh, you did that.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks (+1), I posted an answer but this approach is database specific, i.e. the "lower" function.  Although lower() does actually work in all major SQL implementations I would prefer a 'ruby/rails' approach that is database agnostic and which would allow me to do more complicated expressions the way I can with sort_by

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
Use order("lower(name)")
```

but is not ideal as it used a sql function not a ruby function so is database independent - that said - lower() does exist in most sql implementations, including mySQL, Postgres, sqlserver and Oracle.  But for this and other, similar operations I would prefer to use a Ruby approach.